# ng-bootstrap removes "dev": true flag from multiple packages in package-lock.json

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

`Angular v17`, `ng-bootstrap v16`. I create new project with "ng new ...", and then add `ng-bootstrap` with "npm install ng-bootstrap". Then, I check what changed in `package-lock.json`, and I see that many packages have their "dev": true flag removed. For example `"@angular/compiler-cli", "@babel/core"` and so on.

Why is it doing this?